# How to interpret the ending of Perfect Strangers?

Tags: plot-explanation, perfect-strangers

In the Italian movie *Perfetti sconosciuti* (eng. *Perfect Strangers*) the characters at the end of the movie act like the previous events, which unfolded during the movie didn't happen. How should one interpret this ending? Are they only pretending it didn't happen, or did it really not happen in some weird way?

Comment: ["At the end of the evening, it is revealed that in reality the mobile phone game never happened, thanks to strong opposition from Rocco"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_Strangers_(2016_film)#Plot)

Comment: @BCdotWEB so it was just a "what-if" imaginary scenario showing what would be if they played the game?